# Vuejs Display certain div when radio button is checked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I display `divA` when radio button **A** is checked and display `divB` when radio button **B** is checked?

```
<b-form-radio value="A">A</b-form-radio>
<b-form-radio value="B">B</b-form-radio>

<!-- divA -->

<div>
...
</div>

<!-- divB -->
<div>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your custom radio control (`b-form-radio`) supports `v-model`, you can do this:

```
<b-form-radio v-model="selected" value="A">A</b-form-radio>
<b-form-radio v-model="selected" value="B">B</b-form-radio>

<!-- divA -->
<div v-show="selected === 'A'">
...
</div>

<!-- divB -->
<div v-show="selected === 'B'">
...
</div>
```

Additionally, in your component **data function**, you need to make `selected` as a reactive property:

```
{
  data() {
    return {
      // Initially selected will be null
      // to hide both the div
      selected: null
    }
  }
}
```

In summary, it is the combination of `v-show` directive together with `v-model`. Also, you can use `v-if` instead of `v-show` if you do not want other div to be rendered at all on the page.